# Do I really need Macbook to do Ruby on Rails development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm starting to learn Ruby on Rails but this question is bugging me.

As I visited a lot of Ruby on Rails site and talked to a lot of Ruby on Rails dev I know, most of them are using Macbook to do the development.

Even I know that Ubuntu is also a good platform to do the development. But, why not so much people using it. The point is, a laptop with Ubuntu is much cheaper compare to Macbook Pro. It's almost $500 in different at my location, which is quite a lot of money for me. But, I can pay for it if Macbook is really better.

So, Is there any pros and cons that I'm not aware of? And, do I really need Macbook to do Ruby on Rails development?

Comment: Because people buy expensive stuff to make them feel better and can afford to? In reality you can develop on anything that supports Ruby.

Comment: People use Apple hardware because it is good, but it is not necessary.

Comment: 'People buy [macs] to make them feel better' is the kind of irrational comment that bugs me. Agreeing with Patrick I'll add that OSX is just wonderful to use 60+ hours a week.

Comment: @mark, yes, perhaps my comment does sound little like troll bait, and I do apologise for that. Then again, phrase ["Apple hardware"](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) is just as irrational. After all, it's mostly overpriced Intel components in nice casing IMHO. But enough about laptops, bottom line is you can develop on any platform supporting Ruby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu is fine for ruby on rails development, in fact, I prefer it over developing on OSX.

It just so happens that a lot of the rails community use Macs as their development machine.

I would not recommend using windows though since there are a lot of rails/ruby tools that use shell scripts.

If you're developing on ubuntu, don't use the ruby version from apt-get, download the source from the website and compile that, it comes with ruby gems so you can get started right away with gem install rails.

Comment: Agreed - I have a Mac now, but I did all my Ruby development on Ubuntu before that, and using the system packages was a bit of a pain to be honest! It's one of those situations where you really do have to roll your own (or use RVM!).

Answer (score 3):

I used RoR on Win XP for years without any issues, then I switched to Ubuntu and saw what I was missing :)

Whatever OS platform you use there will be installation configurations that you will need to understand that are specific to your platform. If on Ubuntu or any other *nix OS you do not want to use sudo to install RoR or Ruby gems. It will cause you problems.

Suggestion - This is one of those times where you really need to just do it and find out for yourself rather than talking about it.
Check out the RoR site here http://rubyonrails.org/download. If you are on Windows use the windows installer. It's all there on that page I linked to so go for it and have fun :)